# Displaying record count with fetchColumn

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, pdo

I'm trying check size of a select in my data base. I have a table `estado` and I want to check if this table has a record 'TO', if this table has this record return 1 if not return 0. To do it I'm trying use `fetchColumn()` but does always return 0. 
I can't understand why because my table has this record so it should return 1.

How could I do it ?

```
public function isEstadoExist($estado){
        $stm = $this->conexao->prepare("SELECT * FROM estado t1 WHERE t1.estado = ?");
        $stm->bindParam(1, $estado);
        $existe = $stm->fetchColumn();
        echo $existe; //always display 0

    }
```

Comment: You did not `execute()` => `$stm->execute();` => http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Comment: ^ if that worked (which I'm confident it will), you can delete the question. It's been answered.

Comment: your question title is contradicting to what your really want to do inside the question body. if you just want to know if that particular with a certain value exists, just use a `COUNT()` clause and fetch that column, if its greater than zero then it exists, and as Fred has said, execute the statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as @Fred -ii- say, you must call $stm->execute, and I modify the SQL.

```
 public function isEstadoExist($estado){
            $stm = $this->conexao->prepare("SELECT count(*) as cant FROM estado t1 WHERE t1.estado = ?");
            $stm->bindParam(1, $estado);
            $stm->execute();
            $existe = $stm->fetchColumn();
            echo $existe;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
public function isEstadoExist($estado){

    $query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM estado t1 WHERE t1.estado = %s", filter_var($estado, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
    # Be careful the value of the column "estado" might have different case than that of "$estado"

    $stm = $this->conexao->select($query);

   return ($stm->rowCount()== 1) ? 1 : 0;
   # I prefer "return ($stm->rowCount()) ? true : false;"
}
```

There is no need to bind or fetch from the PDO statement if you just want to check if the record exist.

Comment: This is wrong and for quite a few reasons. You're also missing the point.

Comment: Can you please tell me why? I honestly want to know.

Comment: The OP is using PDO with prepared statements which is important to safeguard against SQL injection. Then you're mixing in an `mysql_` function that does not intermix with PDO or any other MySQL API.

Comment: You're right about the Mysql function, I was too specfic. But there is no SQL injection threat for retrieve operation. pdo->select would be fine.

Comment: If the OP feels safer to use prepared statements, then that is up to them. We can suggest, I agree. You will need to modify your answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the constructive criticism, I appreciate it.

Comment: You're quite welcome.